# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: second.style is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a clock showing the local time. Here is the html code:

```
  <body>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="seattle" class="clock rounded-circle">
                        <div class="hand second"></div>
                        <div class="hand hour"></div>
                        <div class="hand minute"></div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my js:

```
  var second = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
  var minute = document.getElementsByClassName("minute");
  var hour = document.getElementsByClassName("hour");
  var curDate = new Date();

  function updateDate() {
    s = curDate.getSeconds();
    m = curDate.getMinutes();
    h = curDate.getHours();

    var hourDeg = (h / 12) * 360 + ((m / 60) / 12) * 360 + (((s / 60) / 60) / 12) * 360;
    var minuteDeg = (m / 60) * 360 + ((s / 60) / 60) * 360;
    var secondDeg = (s / 60) * 360;

    second.style.transform = `rotate(${ secondDeg }deg)`;
    minute.style.transform = `rotate(${ minuteDeg }deg)`;
    hour.style.transform = `rotate(${ hourDeg }deg)`; 
  }
  //setInterval(updateDate, 1000);
  updateDate();
```

css:

```
.minute {
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 90px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
}

.hour {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 11, 235);
    height: 60px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
}

.second {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(191, 22, 22);
    height: 90px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

Why it shows "Uncaught TypeError: second.style is undefined"? The "second" has been declared in the html and the css contains its style. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you got your answer then acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName()` will return an array of html elements. You need to iterate over them.

> Possible solution with your existing code

```js
// change
second[0].style.transform = `rotate(${ secondDeg }deg)`;
minute[0].style.transform = `rotate(${ minuteDeg }deg)`;
 hour[0].style.transform = `rotate(${ hourDeg }deg)`;
```

`second[0]` is the first child with the class name `second`.

### By using ID

```html
<!--html-->
<div id="second" class="hand second"></div>
<div id="hour" class="hand hour"></div>
<div id="minute" class="hand minute"></div>
```

```js
// javascript

// just access elements like this
let second = document.getElementById("second");
let hour = document.getElementById("hour");
let minute = document.getElementById("minute");
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

`document.getElementsByClassName('**')[0]`

as it returns an array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like collection (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). You'll need to loop over each element.  This can be done like this:

```
Array.from(second).forEach(el => {
  el.style.transform = `rotate(${ secondDeg }deg)`;
});
```

Of course, you'll need to repeat this for `minute` and `hour`, too.